# Como quitar el + de la extensión del país para guardarlo en un arreglo

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un script en Google Spreadsheet y cuando guardo el valor del teléfono con extensión del país y lo llevo a otro Google Spreadsheet en la nueva hoja me pone `#ERROR!`.

Es porque al poner el `+` en la celda se pone `=` y el teléfono, y eso no es una función.

¿Cómo podría hacer para que saliera la extensión del país?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Has probado a poner una comilla simple al principio de la cadena?  EJ:

```
'+00346595650
```

Comment: No lo he probado, como tendria que hacerlo?, ten en cuenta que trabajo con codigo php, este codigo <code>'telefono' => $_SESSION['phone2'],</code> esta dentro de un if que es el que añade los valores al google spread sheet

Comment: Hola, el PHP no es mi fuerte, pero supongo que con:

    'telefono' => "'" . $_SESSION['phone2'] 

debería funcionar

Comment: Alguien podria verificar lo que ha dicho el compañero?

Comment: Comprobado, funciona gracias David Porqueras